# Columns not returning correctly when using WIQL Queries from ADO

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am trying to get all Epics from ADO using the below code

```
    string PAT = "sdsd";

    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
            new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic",
            Convert.ToBase64String(
                System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(
                    string.Format("{0}:{1}", "", PAT))));
        string query = "SELECT [System.Id], [System.WorkItemType], [System.Title], [System.State], [System.AreaPath], [System.IterationPath], [System.TeamProject], [System.WorkItemType] FROM workitems WHERE System.WorkItemType='Epic' ORDER BY [System.ChangedDate] DESC ";
        var q = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new WiqlQuery() { query = query });
        using (HttpResponseMessage response =client.PostAsync("https://dev.azure.com/{Org}/_apis/wit/wiql?api-version=6.0",new StringContent(q,Encoding.UTF8,"application/json")).GetAwaiter().GetResult())
        {
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            string responseBody = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            string k = "";
        }
    }
```

Code executes without any trouble. But if I run the above query in ADO query editor, its returning all the columns in the Select statement.

But when I run the same in Code, I am not all getting any of those columns. Instead I am getting below JSON

```
{
    "queryType": "flat",
    "queryResultType": "workItem",
    "asOf": "2021-07-02T08:30:15.84Z",
    "columns": [
        {
            "referenceName": "System.Id",
            "name": "ID",
            "url": "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/wit/fields/System.Id"
        },
        {
            "referenceName": "System.WorkItemType",
            "name": "Work Item Type",
            "url": "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/wit/fields/System.WorkItemType"
        },
        {
            "referenceName": "System.Title",
            "name": "Title",
            "url": "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/wit/fields/System.Title"
        },
        {
            "referenceName": "System.State",
            "name": "State",
            "url": "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/wit/fields/System.State"
        },
        {
            "referenceName": "System.AreaPath",
            "name": "Area Path",
            "url": "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/wit/fields/System.AreaPath"
        },
        {
            "referenceName": "System.IterationPath",
            "name": "Iteration Path",
            "url": "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/wit/fields/System.IterationPath"
        },
        {
            "referenceName": "System.TeamProject",
            "name": "Team Project",
            "url": "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/wit/fields/System.TeamProject"
        },
        {
            "referenceName": "System.WorkItemType",
            "name": "Work Item Type",
            "url": "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/wit/fields/System.WorkItemType"
        }
    ],
    "sortColumns": [
        {
            "field": {
                "referenceName": "System.ChangedDate",
                "name": "Changed Date",
                "url": "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/wit/fields/System.ChangedDate"
            },
            "descending": true
        }
    ],
    "workItems": [
        {
            "id": 61380,
            "url": "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/wit/workItems/613810"
        },
        {
            "id": 61834
        }
    ]
}
```

What could be the reason or how to get all the columns of data we have specified in Select statement

Answer (score 0):

Yes, RUN WIQL returns only the list of ids. Then you can use [Get Work Items Batch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/get%20work%20items%20batch?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1) to get only needed fields:

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/_apis/wit/workitemsbatch?api-version=6.1-preview.1

BODY:
{
  "ids": [
    297,
    299,
    300
  ],
  "fields": [
    "System.Id",
    "System.Title",
    "System.WorkItemType",
    "Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.RemainingWork"
  ]
}
```

Comment: That is something I have tried, but there is a limitation of only 200 records in a batch. When there are more than 100k records, that will take some time to loop

Comment: This API gets more twisty by the second. Is there a simple endpoint to pull the list of all items WITHOUT having to iterate?